# Php Gamma Distribution Inverse different from Excel

Tags: php, excel, gamma-distribution

To calculate the Gamma Inverse. 
I am using the phpExcel library :

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation/Statistical.php

I use this library and compare it to the result from Excel.
For both in Php and Excel I have tested with the same values but got different results:

Php:
   GAMMAINV(0.999 , 21.054, 1/0.266)
Result : 395.75187969925

In Excel : =GAMMA.INV(0.999 , 21.054, 1/0.266)
Result : 143.076

Tests with the BETA.INV and BETAINV worked perfectly.
So I don't understand what is going wrong here.
Could someone explain and or point out a correct library?

Comment: Perhaps you could actually look at the code yourself and see where it's going wrong, if your understanding of the maths behind these functions is good. It is an open source project, meaning that the source code is accessible (you've even linked to it).... and I'm sure that if PHPExcel is incorrect, then the developers would love to know what's wrong and what might be done to fix it

Comment: Well my understanding of the maths behind this isn't good at all. Which makes it at lot more difficult to see what is wrong. But I'll also check with the developers. I did not think about that.

Comment: I got stats_cdf_gamma working from PECL stats.

Comment: I looked at the code and it indeed returns very different results from Excel. Without understanding the math myself or being able to compare it with the underlying Excel code, my guess would be the problem has something to do with the value of the xHi variable in the GAMMAINV function. That seems to have a huge effect on outcome. I can tweak it to get close to my Excel output, but can never get it to match it consistently. Hopefully the developers @MarkBaker will have a better understanding of the code and how it might be "fixed" :)

Answer (score 0):

In R I get: qgamma(0.999, 21.054, 1/0.266) = 10.13834
Very different from the Excel result: GAMMA.INV(0.999, 21.054, 1/0.266)= 143.2859273
Trusting R, I think Excel computes incorrectly, but not always; For example:
Excel: GAMMA.INV(0.025,10,1) = 4.795388696
R: qgamma(.025,10,1) = 4.795389

It looks therefore to me that **both** Excel and phpExcel give unreliable quantiles for the gamma function!